# Unable to Install Salesforce Data Loader v52 in Mac BigSur 11.4

Tags: data-loader, mac-os-x

Getting Error while starting 'install.command' in my Mac BigSur 11.4:

> “install.command” cannot be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.
> macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware.

I tried bypassing this security warning from "System Preference -> Security & Privacy: General tab, but it didn't solve the issue.

Any ideas or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same issue. I found a solution to the problem. I removed the quarantine attribute from the file which allowed me to open it normally.

I used the terminal command: `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine install.command`

Comment: This worked for me for not just Data Loader but also for Installing Sentinel.pkg for Salesforce Certification.

Many Thanks !!

Answer (score 5):

It may be because your JRE version is not correct. To check this and fix it, try this:

[For MacOS]:

> Go into where the data loader is installed and execute it from the command line so you can see the error message (instead of the app trying to open and closing immediately w/o warning.)

1. In a terminal window, cd to:

> /dataloader/v54.0.0/dataloader.app/Contents/MacOS

2. From the prompt, run the executable:

> ./dataloader

3. You may see an error message like this:

> Java JRE 11 or later is not installed. For example, download and install Zulu OpenJDK 11 or later JRE for macOS from https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/zulu-mac/

4. Download the latest JRE from the Azul site (use the DMG for MacOS). Then re-launch the Dataloader app (from the Application folder or wherever you installed it.)

**Should launch completely now.**

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_install_mac.htm

1. Install Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 11 or later, for
   example, Zulu OpenJDK version 11 or later for macOS using the .DMG
   file.
2. From Setup, download the Data Loader installation file.
3. Right-click the .zip file and select Extract All.
4. In the Data Loader folder, double-click the installer.command file. **If you can’t open the file because of an unidentified developer message, press the Control key while clicking the installer.command file**, and select
   open from the menu.
5. Specify where to install Data Loader.
6. Specify whether to add a Data Loader launch icon on your desktop or Applications folder. Data Loader completes the installation.

Comment: I tried all of above, no changes in my situation of error.